# How to run django application on google app engine without using gunicorn

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I have gone through all the documentation provided for the running Django Application on app engine.
I have a Django Application where I am using Vision and Storage clients and my app name is pvd.
I have been constantly getting below errors in error logs.

```
A  [2017-03-30 22:08:07 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7) 
A  [2017-03-30 22:08:07 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7) 
A  [2017-03-30 22:08:07 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9 
A  [2017-03-30 22:12:35 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9) 
A  [2017-03-30 22:12:35 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9) 
A  [2017-03-30 22:12:36 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11 
A  [2017-03-30 22:13:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term 
A  [2017-03-30 22:13:03 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7) 
A  [2017-03-30 22:13:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master*
```

Below is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT pythonvision.wsgi

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Below is my requirement.txt

```
Django==1.10.6
google-cloud-storage==0.23.1
google-cloud-vision==0.23.1
gunicorn==19.7.0
```

For deploying I am using:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855197/gunicorn-worker-timeout-error) to someone else seeing gunicorn worker timeouts?

Comment: `Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
[2017-03-31 00:28:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.0
[2017-03-31 00:28:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1)
[1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[1] [INFO] Server is ready. Spawning workers
[7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[7] [INFO] Worker spawned (pid: 7)
Failed to find application: 'pythonvision'
[7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[INFO] Shutting down: Master
 [1] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.`

Comment: Created new config.py
In app.yaml: entrypoint: gunicorn -c config.py pythonvision:app

`Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
[1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.0
[1] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1)
[1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[1] [INFO] Server is ready. Spawning workers
[7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[7] [INFO] Worker spawned (pid: 7)
Failed to find application: 'pythonvision'
[7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[INFO] Shutting down: Master
 [1] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.`

Answer (score 0):

Update `gunicorn` command with a `timeout` that suits your needs.

E.g (60 seconds):

```
entrypoint: gunicorn --timeout 60 -b :$PORT pythonvision.wsgi
```

I believe the default is 30 seconds.