# Catch gunicorn errors in GAE flex

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, app-engine-flexible

I've got a GAE Flex/Flask/Python app.  I do some processing that is usually very quick, but sometimes it exceeds gunicorn's timeout, and my app displays this very ugly response:

```
502 Bad Gateway 
----------
nginx
```

I would like to catch these gunicorn errors and instead display a much more user friendly error message with Flask.

My Flask code is wrapped in a try/except block like this:

```
try:
    do_processing()
except Exception:
    show_error_msg()
```

but my code never gets to `show_error_msg()`.

I was hoping someone had a good solution for this.

Comment: Can't you increase `gunicorn`'s timeout? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855197/gunicorn-worker-timeout-error

Comment: Probably a strong case here for investigating job queues like `rq` or `celery`.  Heavy processing then gets done in a background task, away from the wsgi process.

Comment: @v25, that's a good suggestion.  I could submit the request using AJAX on the front end.  That might be easier for me.